# How to find the (1,1) entry in this dynamical system?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, dynamical-systems

Here's the question:
Consider the dynamical system $V_{k+1}$ = $AV_k$ where

$$ 
A=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
-13 & 4\\
\end{pmatrix}
\quad \text{and} \quad 
V_0=\begin{pmatrix}
 1 \\
3 
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Find a formula in terms of k for the $(1,1)$-entry $x_k$ of $V_k$.

Can anyone help point me in the right direction for this? my first though to Diagonalize *A* and use the formula $V_k = PD^kP^-1V_0$, but all I got wax this insanely janky looking vector that I know is wrong. How are you supposed to find the formula for *k* in this instance?

Comment: Show us how you diagonalized $A$ (it was a good idea).

Comment: Why do you speak of (1,1) entry for $V_k$ as if it was a $2\times2$-matrix?

Comment: I used a calculator for that so I could speed things up. If you need it, I can show you what I got.

Comment: I'm assuming so, what I kept getting was a 2x1 Matrix

Comment: $D=\left( \begin{array}{cc} 2+3 i & 0 \\ 0 & 2-3 i \\ \end{array} \right),$ $P=\left( \begin{array}{cc} \frac{2-3 i}{\sqrt{182}} & \frac{2+3 i}{\sqrt{182}} \\ \sqrt{\frac{13}{14}} & \sqrt{\frac{13}{14}} \\ \end{array} \right).$ Then use your formula $V_k = PD^kP^{-1}V_0.$

Comment: Alternatively, because of this formula and of the fact that the two components $x_k,y_k$ of $V_k$ are real (by induction), you know that $x_k={\rm Re}((a+ib)(2+3i)^k)$ for $a,b\in\Bbb R$ easy to determine, knowing $x_0$ and $x_1.$

Comment: Why have you posted this question twice? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4596653/how-to-find-a-formula-for-k-in-a-dynamical-system

Answer (score 1):

As explained in the comments,
$$x_k={\rm Re}((a+ib)(2+3i)^k)$$
with $a,b\in\Bbb R$ determined by $1=x_0=a$ and $3=x_1=2a-3b,$ i.e. $a=1$ and $b=-\frac13.$

Comment: what does $Re$ stand for?

Comment: If you type `\Re`,  in math mode, you get a fancy output for the real part of a complex number.   Similarly `\Im`.

Comment: @DreamCloud [Real part](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number#Definition)

Comment: @eggnog thank you I know but I prefer that typo, which is very common as well.

Answer (score 0):

Diagonalization seems to work:

$$D=\begin {pmatrix}2+3i\quad 0\\0\quad 2-3i\end {pmatrix}$$, with the eigenvalues on the diagonal.

For $P$ we need a basis of eigenvectors.   I got $$P=\begin{pmatrix}1\quad 1\\2+3i\quad 2-3i\end {pmatrix}$$.

So, we should have $A^k=PD^kP^{-1}$.

$P^{-1}=\dfrac i6\begin{pmatrix}2-3i\quad-2-3i\\-1\quad 1\end {pmatrix}$,

and the rest is a straight forward calculation.

Answer (score -1):

Obviously,

$ V_k = A^k V_0 $

Now,

$ A^k = \alpha_0 I + \alpha_1 A \hspace{30pt} (*)$

To find $\alpha_0$ and $\alpha_1$, we use the eigenvalues of $A$.

The characteristic polynomial of $A$ is $ \lambda^2 - 4 \lambda + 13 = 0 $

whose roots (the eigenvalues) are $\lambda_1= 2 - 3 i $ and $ \lambda_2 = 2 + 3 i $

Substitute this in the above equation, i.e.

$ \lambda_1^k = \alpha_0 + \alpha_1 \lambda_1 $

$ \lambda_2^k = \alpha_0 + \alpha_1 \lambda_2 $

Solving this linear system in $\alpha_0, \alpha_1 $ we get

$\alpha_0 = \dfrac{ \lambda_2 \lambda_1^{k} - \lambda_1 \lambda_2^k }{ \lambda_2 - \lambda_1 } $

$\alpha_1 = \dfrac{ \lambda_2^k - \lambda_1^k } {\lambda_2 - \lambda_1} $

Now, we have

$ \lambda_2 - \lambda_1 = 6 i $

$ \lambda_1^k = \sqrt{13} e^{-i k \phi} , \lambda_2^k = \sqrt{13} e^{i k \phi} $

where $ \phi = \tan^{-1} \dfrac{3}{2} $

Substituting this, and simplifying,

$ \alpha_0 = - \dfrac{13^{(k+1)/2}}{3} \sin( ( k - 1) \phi ) $

$ \alpha_1 = \dfrac{13^{k/2}}{3} \sin (k \phi ) $

Substituting these in equation (*) above, then

$ A^k = \begin{bmatrix} - \dfrac{13^{(k+1)/2}}{3} \sin( ( k - 1) \phi ) && \dfrac{13^{k/2}}{3} \sin (k \phi )  \\  -13 \dfrac{13^{k/2}}{3} \sin (k \phi ) &&  - \dfrac{13^{(k+1)/2}}{3} \sin( ( k - 1) \phi ) + 4 \dfrac{13^{k/2}}{3} \sin (k \phi ) \end{bmatrix} $

Hence,

$ V_k = A^k V_0 = \begin{bmatrix}- \dfrac{13^{(k+1)/2}}{3} \sin( ( k - 1) \phi ) + 13^{k/2} \sin (k \phi ) \\  - \dfrac{13^{k/2}}{3} \sin (k \phi )  - 13^{(k+1)/2} \sin( ( k - 1) \phi ) \end{bmatrix} $